# Apache JMeter recording issue 403 Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, certificate, jmeter

My application is accessible via Safari browser but while I am recording it using JMeter, after the SSO authentication I am getting a 403 access denied.

It appears to be a certificate related issue, as while recording, the browser prompts that the certificate is not trusted and I hit continue.

The server is Apache Tomcat.

Ia m using JMeter 2.11 and while recording, I am using the HTTPS proxy which is generating the CA certificate in the bin directory.

I also tried installing the certificate in Firefox and tried that too but no luck.

Comment: When you setup your manual proxy config in your browser, did you also setup a SSL proxy in addition to HTTP-80, and then filter it through the same port 8080?

Comment: yes, I set up the SSL proxy and routed it through the same port(in manual proxy settings)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I use to test SSL sites with Jmeter:

1. I recommend using Java 1.7.0_xx
2. Clone this project and run Jmeter from it:
   https://github.com/djangofan/run-jmeter-with-plugins-via-build-tools
3. Open browser, hit the https (SSL) site that you want to test.
4. If site is https then then the browser will show a “LOCK” icon that
   specifies its secure.
5. Open the “Certificate Information” and export
   the certificate as a .pem or .der file.
6. In the 'jre/lib/security' folder of the JDK that you started Jmeter with, edit the security.policy file. Comment out the line that says:
   **#jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024**
7. Now using java keytool.exe convert exported file to .jks 
   **keytool -importcert -alias mycert -file exportedFile.der -keystore jmeterTrustedKeystore.jks -storepass changeit**
8. Restart or re-open Jmeter and use the Options → SSL Manager menu to load the .jks keystore. It should prompt you for the “changeit” password and then    Jmeter will remember it.
9. Create a new SSL request and it should now
   succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following recommendations from [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide, to wit:

1. Configure your browser to user JMeter's proxy for all protocols
2. Clear your browser's history, cache, cookies, etc.